# past and present with models when using conditionals

Tags: conditionals

what would be the context to use below sentence.
I **could** get in trouble **If** I **did** that.
I **will** get in trouble **If**  I **do** that.

**Would** Tom accept your help **If** you **offered** it.
**Will** Tom accept your help **If** you **offer** it.

Comment: The first of each pair refer to a hypothetical situation, the second is a prediction. "If I do that I will _definitely_ get into trouble." "Supposing I were to do that, I could possibly get into trouble."

Comment: @KateBunting, could you please explain these,
If he invited me, I would go to his party. If he had invited me, I would have gone to his party.

Comment: In the first, the party hasn't happened yet (so the speaker may still receive an invitation). In the second, the party has already happened and the speaker was not invited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *could* versus *will*:

```
                                          Chance of getting in trouble
                                          if you do that

I could get in trouble if I did that      Not 100% - trouble is able to happen

I will get in trouble if I do that.       100%
```

For *would* versus *will* - the difference is subtle and honestly there is not a lot of difference between the two questions.

> Will Tom accept your help if you offer it?

The asker of this question probably already knows that Tom will accept help when offered.

> Would Tom accept your help if you offer it?

The asker of this question probably doesn't know for sure that Tom will accept help when offered.  The asker is using you to gain that information.

Answer (score 0):

Just because If condition having "did" or past tense(offered) doesn't mean the action is completed.

These are comes under **contrary to the present facts** or **hypothetical situation** or **unlikely**. These conditions maybe true in the future or some other time,